# Firebase App Distribution failed to fetch app information: [400] Request contains an invalid argument on multi-firebase Android project setup

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-app-distribution

I have an Android app that has 2 different firebase projects, one for DEBUG builds and one for RELEASE and they have their `google-services.json` file respectively.

```
app
|-src/main/debug
| |-google-services.json (Points to Firebase with ID: `myapp-debug`)
|-src/main/release
| |-google-services.json (Points to Firebase with ID: `myapp-release`)
```

I have the `app/build.gradle` setup such that both RELEASE and DEBUG builds are posted to the `myapp-debug` Firebase project. The `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable is set to service account JSON for `myapp-debug` Firebase project.

```
android {
    // ... more configs here
    buildTypes/debug {
        firebaseAppDistribution {
            releaseNotes = "DEBUG"
            apkPath = "/path/to/debug.apk"
            groups = "qa, devs"
        }


        buildTypes/release {
            firebaseAppDistribution {
                appId="myapp-debug" // Force release builds to same debug Firebase project
                releaseNotes = "RELEASE"
                apkPath = "/path/to/release.apk"
                groups = "qa, devs"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I build app, and try to publish using `appDistributionUpload*` command I get an error for **RELEASE** build.

```
./gradlew clean assembleDebug
./gradlew assembleRelease

./gradlew appDistributionUploadDebug         # This command succeeds
./gradlew appDistributionUploadRelease       # This one fails with failed to fetch app information
```

**So, I am confused about what could go wrong here**. What is the role of `appId` config inside `firebaseAppDistribution` block?

---

For reference, here is the log for each `appDistributionUpload` command.

```
> Task :ClassifiedsApp:appDistributionUploadDebug
Using APK path specified by the apkPath parameter in your app's build.gradle: /myapp/build/outputs/apk/debug/debug-app.apk.
Uploading APK to Firebase App Distribution...
Getting appId from output of google services plugin
Using credentials file specified by environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ****
This APK has not been uploaded before.
Uploading the APK.
Uploaded APK successfully 202
Added release notes successfully 200
Added testers/groups successfully 200
App Distribution upload finished successfully!



> Task :ClassifiedsApp:appDistributionUploadRelease FAILED
Using APK path specified by the apkPath parameter in your app's build.gradle: /myapp/build/outputs/apk/release/release-app.apk.
Uploading APK to Firebase App Distribution...
Getting appId from build.gradle file
Using credentials file specified by environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ****
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ClassifiedsApp:appDistributionUploadRelease'.
> App Distribution failed to fetch app information: [400] Request contains an invalid argument.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have contacted Firebase support team and Kyle from support team have reached back to me.

My mistake was, based on [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-gradle#step_3_configure_your_distribution_properties) for `appId` it was referring to the `mobilesdk_app_id`, and **NOT** the Firebase `project_id` that I have used.

See simplified `google-services.json` file below.

```
{
   "project_info":{
      "project_id":"firebase-project-id"
   },
   "client":[
      {
         "client_info":{
            "mobilesdk_app_id":"1:543212345:android:93690bfb936b9c",
            "android_client_info":{
               "package_name":"app.package.name"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

So, the fix was to use the `mobilesdk_app_id` value as `appId` in the `firebaseAppDistribution` block.

```
    buildTypes/release {
        firebaseAppDistribution {
            appId="1:543212345:android:93690bfb936b9c" // Force release builds to same debug Firebase project
            releaseNotes = "RELEASE"
            apkPath = "/path/to/release.apk"
            groups = "qa, devs"
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's best not to share your app id in public (if that's your real App Id).

Comment: @Chintan this is a fake app id. Also, you can get this info from any app by inspecting any APK.

Comment: @Chintan It's very easy to access the google-services.json of an app. This file does not contain any credential information.